# Trouble converting JSON Ints to Strings (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, json, swift, type-conversion

New to Swift and coding in general. Trying to put an array of JSON objects into a tableView. Having trouble converting my Ints to Strings in the tableView delegate method's detailTextView.text. Getting an error "Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Int?' conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible.'" Try to use that, but it's a rabbit hole of errors from there. Been browsing SO most of the day but no luck.

```
class AllCountriesVC: UITableViewController {


    struct CovidData: Codable {
        let country: String
        let cases: Int?
        let todayCases: Int?
        let deaths: Int?
        let todayDeaths: Int?
        let recovered: Int?
        let active: Int?
        let critical: Int?
        let totalTests: Int?
    }


    var data = [CovidData]()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        load()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
    }

    func load() {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries/") {
        let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
            self.data = try! JSONDecoder().decode([CovidData].self, from: jsonData)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count ?? 1       
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let countryData = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = countryData.country
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(countryData.cases)
        //this is where it fails with error "Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Int?' conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible'"

        return cell
    } 
}
```

Comment: `countryData.cases` is optional: can be nil. `String.init(_:)` that you use expect a non-optional `Int`. So you can use a default value if it's nil like 0: `String(countryData.cases ?? 0)`: ie: if countryData.cases is nil, use 0, else use countryData.cases and init a string with that "sure existing" (non-optional) value.

Comment: The nil coalescing operator in `numberOfRowsInSection` is pointless. Didn’t you notice the warning ⚠️?

Comment: Larme, That did it, thank you!!  Vadian, I did notice that. Was taught to keep it there as a failsafe.

Comment: The *teacher* is wrong. A non-optional cannot be `nil`, never.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the data, the only property that has null data is `recovered`, so you change the rest of the properties to non-optionals.  This will make things a lot easier for you.

I would also recommend that you use `do/try/catch` rather than `try!`.

```
class AllCountriesVC: UITableViewController {
    struct CovidData: Codable {
        let country: String
        let cases: Int
        let todayCases: Int
        let deaths: Int
        let todayDeaths: Int
        let recovered: Int?
        let active: Int
        let critical: Int
        let totalTests: Int
    }


    var data = [CovidData]()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        load()
    }

    func load() {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries/") {
            do {
                let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                self.data = try JSONDecoder().decode([CovidData].self, from: jsonData)

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count ?? 1       
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let countryData = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = countryData.country
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(countryData.cases)
        return cell
    } 
}
```

If you did want to use an optional, say `recovered` then you can use the nil coalescing operator - `??`

```
String(countryData.recovered ?? 0)
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much!! Appreciate the tip on the do/catch block as well.